# Command line Bin to local Printer

Tags: printer, prompt

I am trying to run a bin file from the command prompt to a local printer connected via usb. The line I am using is:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /b PAItx2002f /a %windi
r%\desktop\F2ITX2_206.bin
```

The printer name is PAItx2002f. The file I am running is located C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\F@ITX@_206.bin.

When I try to run this line, I get the error message "The arguments are invalid".

I am running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Microsoft's documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624057(WS.10).aspx), there shouldn't be a space between the /b and /a switches and their file names.

Also, unless the command is being run from a batch file, the `%windir%` environment variable will not be replaced with an actual directory.

Comment: I used the following line
    
    C:\Users\Administrator>rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry  
    /bPAItx2002f/aC:\Users\Administrators\Desktop\F2ITX2_206.bin

Still received same error.

Comment: I also did it like this

    C:\Users\Administrator>rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry    
    /bPAItx2002f/aDesktop\F2ITX2_206.bin

Comment: @dan_vitch, try `C:\Users\Administrator>rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /bPAItx2002f /aC:\Users\Administrators\Desktop\F2ITX2_206.bin`. You might also try /n instead of /b.